# Where does this blue cube-shaped object belong?

Tags: unpacking

[image: blue cube-shaped object]

I cannot understand what this blue cube-shaped object is. I cannot find where it belongs. Every place I put it in shows it's wrong. Where should I place this object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That object is a videogame console (it has the form of a Nintendo GameCube) and it goes on the **left or right side of the TV cabinet**.

Plus you can interact with it using the right mouse button (or <kbd>B</kbd> on Xbox-type gamepad).